# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'

Tags: windows

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GeneralInfo](
            @Equipment float)
AS
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO GeneralInfo

```
    SELECT EQUIPMENT.Equipment, EQUIPMENT.Description, RIGHT(EQUIPMENT.UserStatus, 3) AS Saty,  
    EQUIPMENT.UserStatus, case when EQUIPMENT.UserStatus like'%RNT%'  then 'RENTAL' OR EQUIPMENT.UserStatus like'%T&M%' then 'T&M' AND (EQUIPMENT.UserStatus like'%ORS%' then 'FSMA' OR EQUIPMENT.UserStatus like'%INT%' then 'Internal Use') OR (EQUIPMENT.UserStatus like'%DEMO%' then 'DEMO' AND EQUIPMENT.UserStatus like'%LOAN%' then 'LOAN') end as Saty,

    EQUIPMENT.UserStatus, case when EQUIPMENT.UserStatus like'%MTR%' then 'METRO' end as Location,
    case when EQUIPMENT.UserStatus like'%RMT%' then 'REMOTE' end as Location,
    EQUIPMENT.Saty, EQUIPMENT.ObjectType, EQUIPMENT.PG, ZSMR056.SDM, EQUIPMENT.AccountCategory, EQUIPMENT.Location, ZSMR056.ServiceCa, EQUIPMENT.CurrentMeter
    FROM  EQUIPMENT INNER JOIN ZSMR056 ON 
    EQUIPMENT.Equipment = ZSMR056.Equipment

    WHERE EQUIPMENT.proses = 0 AND ZSMR056.proses = 0

END
```

Comment: Please, define this a Question and make it more universal. Having line numbers in question title does  not help. Chek more here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What programming language is this? Please tag